# The "Slip and Slide" Factorisation Method

Tags: quadratics, factoring

A really simple question I'm sure I will regret.

I'm trying to use the Slip and Slide factorisation method for the following equation:

2x<sup>2</sup> - 4x - 6 = 0

If I try to use the method I get the answer:

(x + 1)(x - 3) = 0

Which I believe is incorrect. How have I gone wrong in this method?

Comment: Take into account the coefficient of x^2

Comment: Both equations are equivalent.Just multiply by the leading coefficient for the 2nd equation.

Comment: @N-N I reached the stage where (x + 2) (x - 6) = 0 but as per the method I divided the integers by the leading coefficient 2 - so why would I multiply by it, when I haven't had to for other equations with this method?

Comment: (x+1)(x-3) is correct

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Why do you feel it is incorrect?Just try expanding and multiplying by the leading coefficient in the first equation.You will see that it is the same.

Comment: @N-N I feel it's incorrect because in the Slip and Slide method, the final two brackets you're left with should expand into to the original equation without having to multiply by the leading coefficient.

Comment: Are you sure this method guarantees this:"the final two brackets you're left with should expand into to the original equation without having to multiply by the leading coefficient. "?

Comment: Since this is evidently a counter-example.

Comment: @N-N Yep, well that's why I was asking - I'd presumed I had made a mistake somewhere. Alas, if you can't see one, perhaps I just haven't followed the method completely correctly.